# CAML query between farms

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I need to plan and implement search functionality that would allow for search of document libraries based on set of metadata tags. I need to search through multiple document libraries and through multiple farms.

Does anybody implement similar solution? What would be best practices to implement such kind of requirements?

Answer (score 1):

It is certain that the answer to this question depends on what version of SharePoint you are running, which is not specified. That said, in [SharePoint 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh528474.aspx) (and [SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100.aspx)) it is possible to configure cross-farm service applications. Search is a service application so it follows that you could setup a cross-farm search. Although, targeting *specific* document libraries could be tricky; you'd need to configure a content source that included the sites in which the document libraries reside.